# Azure: Could not contact CDS load balancer

Tags: azure, redhat, azure-virtual-machine

After running this scripts

!/bin/bash

```
iptables -F
iptables -X
```

set default policy to drop

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
```

accept everything no matter port on localhost

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

allow input on port 22 (established connections auto accepted

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

allow traffic going to specified outbound ports

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 6667 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 6697 -j ACCEPT
```

drop anything that doesn't match the rules above

```
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP
```

then when I typed on terminal `yum -y update` or anything when I using yum I got this messages

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos
Could not contact CDS load balancer southeastasia-cds2.cloudapp.net, tring others.
Could not contact CDS load balancer southeastasia-cds3.cloudapp.net, tring others.
Could not contact CDS load balancer southeastasia-cds1.cloudapp.net, tring others.


Could not contact any CDS load balancers: southeastasia-cds2.cloudapp.net, southeastasia-cds3.cloudapp.net, southeastasi
a-cds1.cloudapp.net, eastasia-cds4.cloudapp.net.
```

what are the ports for these load balancers for me to allow this in my firewall on redhat??